# Spring @Transactional not working when Hibernate object with lazy loading coming from another transaction is passed down to method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I have a problem with accessing data inside a running transaction when the data came from another (supposedly closed) transaction. I have three classes like below, with an entity (called MyEntity) which also has another entity connected via Hibernate mapping called "OtherEntity" which has lazy loading set to true. Notice how I have two transactions:

- One to load a list of entities
- And a new transaction for each new item

However, this fails inside the loop with "No session" even though I have an active transaction inside the method (TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive is true).

I don't really understand the problem. Seems to me the object which is used by the second transaction(s) "belong" to the first one even though the first transaction was supposed to finish? Maybe its a race condition?

```
@Service
class ServiceA {
    
    @Autowired
    private ServiceB serviceB;

    @Autowired
    private ServiceC serviceC;

    public void test() {
        List<MyEntity> allEntities = serviceC.loadAllEntities(); //First transaction ran, getting a list of entities, but due to lazy loading we havent loaded all the data
        for(MyEntity i : allEntities) {
            serviceB.doOnEach(i); //On each element a new transaction should start
        }
    }

}

@Service
class ServiceB {

    @Transactional
    public void doOnEach(MyEntity entity) {
        System.out.println(TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive()); //true, therefore we have an active transaction here
        OtherEntity other = entity.getSomeOtherEntity(); //Want to load the "lazy loaded" entity here
        //"No Session" exception is thrown here
    }

}

@Service
class ServiceC {
    
    @Autowired
    private MyRepository myRepository;

    @Transactional
    public List<MyEntity> loadAllEntities() {
        return myRepository.findAll();
    }

}
```

A solution would be to re-load the "MyEntity" instance inside the "doOnEach" method, but that seems to me like a sub-optimal solution, especially on big lists. Why would I reload all the data which is already supposed to be there?

Any help is appreciated.

Obviously the real code is a lot more complicated than this but I have to have these kind of separate transactions for business reasons, so please no "solutions" which re-write the core logic of this. I just want to understand whats going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the call to `loadAllEntities()` finishes the Spring proxy commits the transaction and closes the associated Hibernate Session. This means you cannot have Hibernate transparently load the non-loaded lazy associations anymore without explicitly telling it to do so.

If for some reason you really want your associated entities to be loaded lazily the two options you have is either use `Hibernate.initialize(entity.getSomeOtherEntity())` in your `doOnEach()` method or set the `spring.jpa.open-in-view` property to true to have the [OpenSessionInViewInterceptor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate5/support/OpenSessionInViewInterceptor.html) do it for you.

Otherwise it's a good idea to load them together with the parent entity either via `JOIN FETCH` in your repository query or via an Entity Graph.

References:

- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-open-session-in-view
- https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-initialize-proxy-exception

---

To clarify further:

Spring creates a transaction and opens a new Session (A) before entering the `loadAllEntities()` method and commits/closes them upon returning. When you call `entity.getSomeOtherEntity()` the original Session (A) that loaded `entity` is gone (i.e. `entity` is detached) but instead there's a new Session (B) which was created upon entering the `doOnEach()` transactional method. Obviously Session (B) doesn't know anything about `entity` and its relations and at the same time the Hibernate proxy of `someOtherEntity` inside `entity` references the original Session (A) and doesn't know anything about Session (B). To make the Hibernate proxy of `someOtherEntity` actually use the current active Session (B) you can call `Hibernate.initialize()`.

Comment: Thanks, this explains how to circumvent this, but I still don't understand how I cannot access anything in an active session. Are objects tied to the session they came from somehow in a way that you cannot put them into another session/transaction?

Comment: Added more clarification

Comment: To add on: changing `spring.jpa.open-in-view` can be dangerous with significant performance implications. Applications are usually built from the ground up to support it being either enabled or disabled, but probably not both. Make sure you understand what it does before changing it in an existing application.